# Float not working in List-CSS

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having a list which has ng-repeat.
Each item in that List are having property row.
Inside that there are two divs having property float left and right,but that not working.

HTML code-

```
    <html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Radio Buttons</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.12/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Divs inside Div</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content scroll="false">
    <ion-scroll class="list" direction="y" style="height:100%">
      <li class="item"  ng-repeat="item in agendaDetails">
                      <div class="row speakerListItems" ng-repeat="speakering in item.speakers track by $index">
                <div style="float:left">{{speakering.speaker}}</div>
                <div style="float:right">Hello</div>
                          </div>  
      </li>
    </ion-scroll>
  </ion-content>

</body>
</html>
```

Link to Code-[LINK TO CODE](http://codepen.io/rhuldip/pen/MaGmvm)

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping each of your divs in one of the Ionic `col` classes to adhere to the grid framework.

Here's an example using two columns with width of 50% (`col-50`).  I then wrapped the internal content in `<p>` tags and applied the floats to the internal content.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYemvy?editors=101